# jQuery if element contains something, do stuff

Tags: jquery, if-statement, contains

I cannot get this to work.  I simply want to display an alert for test purposes if the proposed `td` contains "OH".

```
 <table id="v65-cart-shipping-details">
     <tr>..</tr>
     <tr>..</tr>
     <tr>
       <td>United States, OH 43112</td>
     <tr>
  </table>
```

No matter what is in it (ie. United States, MI 48187) the alert still pops up, what am I missing?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#v65-cart-shipping-details tr:eq(2) td:contains('OH')")) {
      alert("Did Stuff") }  
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it will return true even if the element isn't found. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#v65-cart-shipping-details tr:eq(2) td:contains('OH')").length) {
      alert("Did Stuff") }  
});
```

Comment: wow, i've been staring at my code to long and could of swore I added length, thanks for being that second set of eyes!

Comment: Well it won't really return `undefined` it just returns an empty array which evaluates to `true`, you're solution does solve this problem though so +1

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be careful here.  If this table is huge in the HTML, this could have the potential to crash a browser (read: IE8-).  If you're generating the html, it'd be much faster to format the address cell like this:

```
 <tr class="address" data-state="OH" data-zip="43112" ... >
   <td>United States, OH 43112</td>
 <tr>
```

Then you could easily select it:

```
if( $("#v65-cart-shipping-details tr.address").is('[data-state="OH"]') )
  alert('mom');
```